# Unvested Stock Part of Overall Compensation Package

Tags: stocks

As part of my overall compensation package I was granted RSUs that are not all vested yet. I will be layed off on 4/5/19. Since the stock was part of overall compensation for time that I clearly was employed, can they take back my stock that is yet to vest or do they need to accelerate it and pay it out?

Comment: Check the grant contract, but unless it's included in a severance package (if you'll be getting one) it's extremely unlikely you'll get the unvested shares.

Answer (score 6):

If it's not vested it's not yours, so they are not "taking away" anything. They *might* accelerate it as part of your severance, but you are not yet *entitled* to the shares.